# How secure is opening another activity?

Tags: android, security, android-activity

I am making an admin app to control the firebase database for my main account, so imagine a 2 structure app
MainActivity and AdminActivity.

So in MainActivity I will have a edittext to input password, if and only if the password matches the hardcoded password then the user can get to the AdminActivity using an intent.

So my question, This app will stay with me only, but in-case it gets into the wrong hands, can someone open the AdminActivity without using the password or with some tool externally? I don't want to implement logging in on Firebase so the database is open.

Comment: Don't think too much. Security is not one thing you can achieve at once. You need to enhance it day by day. Similarly, "optimization is the root of all evil".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone gets ahold of the APK, it is easily decompiled. Even using obfuscation (Proguard) will not hide hardcoded string constants. The attacker can then just try all the strings he finds in your app until he gets the password correctly.

Assuming that your `AdminActivity` is declared as `exported="false"` in the manifest, it would not be possible for an attacker to launch your `Activity` directly (like from another application). However, if the attacker got ahold of the APK, he could install it on a rooted device and do whatever he wants, or he could connect the device to a PC and use ADB to launch the `AdminActivity` directly.

There's probably 6 other successful "bypass the password" scenarios that I can't think of right now off the top of my head.

Comment: Just a note: There are mechanisms you can use to "encrypt" hardcoded strings, some better than others. This just makes it more difficult to crack, but not impossible. There are also alternatives to Proguard that will encrypt or obfuscate string constants.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question can be **Yes** and also **No**

Why **Yes**
Answer: Suppose, while you hardcode the password, you save it somewhere or if anyone tries to look into your computer, then there is a chance of password leakage.

Why **No**
Answer: Because the password is hardcoded, you are the only one who can know the password. There is no way a user can know it.

IMO, for better security, apply a ProGuard to secure your app.